# How to upload folder to server with phpseclib?

Tags: php, phpseclib

I use phpseclib to connect to server and use \Net_SFTP to upload files on server. 
But how to upload a big directory? I use Symfony Finder to collect all local files path in directory:

```
        $finder = new Finder();
        $files = $finder
            ->files()
            ->in($local);

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $from = $file->getRealPath();
            $to = str_replace($local, '', $from);
            $to = rtrim($remote, '/') . '/' . ltrim($to, '/');

            $sftp->put($to, $from, NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);
        }
```

But uploading only root files. phpseclib does not create subdirectories for new files.

How to upload a folder on server using phpseclib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a `chdir()` before each of the put's.